# Stream CopyAsync and WriteAsync on network failures

Tags: c#, async-await

I am doing a copy asynchronous operation on a file stream. I noticed that if an error happen during the operation, I don't receive any error exception.

Tested with a large file, in the middle of the copy operation, suddenly I close the network connection.

After some timeout the test concludes passed.

I Want to be able to capture the whatever error happen during the copy operation.

I copy below.. the code samples, just asking some help.

BR Alex

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert;
using static System.Console;


namespace CopyAsync
{

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        public int BufferSize = 10;

        [TestMethod]
        public void CopyFileAsyncSouldCopyFile()
        {
            BufferSize = 10;
            const string source = @"..\..\UnitTest.cs";
            var destination = Path.GetRandomFileName();

            WriteLine($"Start...");

            var task = CopyAsync(source, destination, action: (total) => WriteLine($"Copying... {total}"));

            var bytes = task.Result;

            WriteLine($"Bytes copied... {bytes}");

            IsTrue(File.Exists(destination));
            AreEqual((new FileInfo(source)).Length, bytes);

            File.Delete(destination);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CopyFileAsyncCancelledSouldCancelCopyFile()
        {
            BufferSize = 10;
            const string source = @"..\..\UnitTest.cs";
            var destination = Path.GetRandomFileName();

            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            WriteLine($"Start...");

            var task = CopyAsync(source, destination, cts.Token,
                (total) =>
                {
                    WriteLine($"Copying... {total}");

                    if (total > 1677)
                        return;

                    cts.Cancel();

                    WriteLine($"Canceled...");
                });

            try
            {
                var bytes = task.Result;               // exception WILL BE thrown here
                WriteLine($"Bytes copied... {bytes}"); // WON'T BE executed
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(TaskCanceledException))
            {
                WriteLine($"TaskCanceledException...");
                File.Delete(destination);
            }
        }


        [TestMethod]
        // Exception not captured 
        // missed: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.
        public void CopyFileAsyncNetworkErrorShouldFail()
        {
            const string source = @"..\..\verybigfile.iso";
            var destination = Path.GetRandomFileName();

            BufferSize = 4096;

            WriteLine($"Start...");
            var task = CopyAsync(source, destination, action: (total) => WriteLine($"Copying... {total}"));

            var bytes = task.Result;                // exception WON'T BE thrown here
            WriteLine($"Bytes copied... {bytes}");  // WILL BE executed
        }


        public async Task<int> CopyAsync(string input, string output, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken), Action<long> action = null)
        {
            using (var source = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, BufferSize, true))
            using (var destination = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, BufferSize, true))
            {

                int bytes;
                var total = 0;
                var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

                while ((bytes = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, token)) > 0)
                {
                    await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytes, token);

                    total += bytes;
                    action?.Invoke(total);
                }

                return total;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which side is over the network, the read or the write?

Comment: the read side is like \\server\sharedFolder\verybigfile.iso,

Comment: Last test is performed coping from an UNC path like \\server\sharedfolder\verybigfile.iso to a hard drive
If while copying I remove the network cable from the desktop, instead of throwing an error the test PASSED. I would do like to have an exception thrown by the system
However if you copy from a removable device like E:\verybigfile.iso and while copying you remove the pen drive, then YES, the system throws an exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file. That is the behavior fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Here I changed a while the code, but here is the working code..

(but indeed I can't figure why now is working, since is more or less the same workflow)

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert;
using static System.Console;


namespace CopyAsync
{

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        private int _bufferSize = 4096;

        [TestMethod]
        public void CopyFileAsyncSouldCopyFile()
        {
            _bufferSize = 100;

            const string source = @"..\..\UnitTest.cs";
            var destination = Path.GetRandomFileName();

            WriteLine($"Start...");

            var task = FileCopyAsync(source, destination, action: total => WriteLine($"Copying... {total}"));

            var bytes = task.Result;

            WriteLine($"Bytes copied... {bytes}");

            IsTrue(File.Exists(destination));
            AreEqual((new FileInfo(source)).Length, bytes);

            File.Delete(destination);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CopyFileAsyncCancelledSouldCancelCopyFile()
        {
            _bufferSize = 100;

            const string source = @"..\..\UnitTest.cs";
            var destination = Path.GetRandomFileName();

            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            WriteLine($"Start...");

            var task = FileCopyAsync(source, destination,
                token: cts.Token,
                action: total =>
                {
                    WriteLine($"Copying... {total}");

                    if (total < 2000)
                        return;

                    cts.Cancel();

                    WriteLine($"Canceled... at {total}");
                });

            try
            {
                task.Wait();               // exception WILL BE thrown here... PERFECT!!!!
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(TaskCanceledException))
            {
                WriteLine($"TaskCanceledException...");
                File.Delete(destination);
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CopyFileAsyncNetworkErrorShouldFail()
        {
            _bufferSize = 4096;

            const string source = @"\\server\sharedfolder\bigfile.iso"; // to test close network connection while copying...
            var destination = Path.GetRandomFileName();

            WriteLine($"Start...");
            var task = FileCopyAsync(source, destination, action: total => WriteLine($"Copying... {total}"));

            try
            {
                task.Wait();                  // exception WILL BE thrown here... PERFECT!!!! more than PERFECT
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(IOException))
            {
                WriteLine($"IOException...");
                File.Delete(destination);
            }
        }

//      ##########################

        public async Task<int> FileCopyAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, bool overwrite = false, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken), Action<long> action = null)
        {
            if (string.Equals(sourceFileName, destFileName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                throw new IOException($"Source {sourceFileName} and destination {destFileName} are the same");

            using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, _bufferSize, true))
            using (var destStream = new FileStream(destFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, _bufferSize, true))
            {
                var bytesCopied = await StreamCopyAsync(sourceStream, destStream, token, action);

                if (bytesCopied != (new FileInfo(sourceFileName)).Length)
                    throw new IOException($"Source {sourceFileName} and destination {destFileName} don't match");

                return bytesCopied;
            }
        }

        public async Task<int> StreamCopyAsync(Stream sourceStream, Stream destStream, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken), Action<long> action = null)
        {
            if (Equals(sourceStream, destStream))
                throw new ApplicationException("Source and destination are the same");

            using (var reg = token.Register(() => Close(sourceStream, destStream))) // disposes registration for token cancellation callback
            {
                int bytes;
                var bytesCopied = 0;
                var buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];

                while ((bytes = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, token)) > 0)
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;

                    await destStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytes, token);

                    bytesCopied += bytes;

                    action?.Invoke(bytesCopied);
                }

                return bytesCopied;
            }
        }

        private static void Close(Stream source, Stream destination) // fires on token cancellation
        {
            source.Close();
            destination.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never like trusting things like `ex.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(IOException)` because using a derived class can break it, normally I test using `ex.InnerException is IOException`